# How do i prove this property of bilinear mapping?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T$ be a Mobius transformation which takes real line onto the unit circle.

Assume $T(z_0)=w_0$.

Then how do i prove that $T(\overline{z_0})=\frac{1}{\overline{w_0}}$?

(Silverman complex analysis p.76)

Answer (score 1):

For every holomorphic $f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$, the function $z\mapsto \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic on the domain you obtain from $U$ by conjugation. Thus

$$z\mapsto T(z)\cdot \overline{T(\overline{z})}$$

is an entire meromorphic function (a rational function, since $T$ is a Möbius transformation).

Apply the identity theorem to reach the desired conclusion.